# Show that $\lfloor(2+\sqrt{3})^n\rfloor$ is an odd integer whenever n is a nonnegative integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, radicals, integers

I know its not right to post a question if I don't have any proofs of my own because most of you will think that I used it as a homework generator. But, can you help me generate proof in this problem? I really don't have any idea how or where to start. Yes, I can illustrate the problem but I can't find ways to start my proof.

Show that $\lfloor(2+\sqrt{3})^n\rfloor$ is an odd integer whenever n is a nonnegative integer

Comment: Hint: Consider $(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n$.

Comment: don't just consider the earlier hint; find the actual values for, say, $n = 0,1,2,3.$ By then it should start to make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left ( 2+\sqrt{3} \right )^{n}+\left ( 2-\sqrt{3} \right )^{n} 
&=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}2^{n-i}\sqrt{3}^i+\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}2^{n-i}(-1)^i\sqrt{3}^i
\\
&=2\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i}2^{n-2i}\sqrt{3}^{2i}
\\
&=2\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i}2^{n-2i}3^{i}
\end{align}
So $(2+\sqrt{3})^{n}+(2-\sqrt{3})^{n}$ is even. Since $0<2-\sqrt{3}<1$, $0<(2-\sqrt{3})^{n}<1$. Thus $\lfloor(2+\sqrt{3})^{n}\rfloor$ is odd.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to solve this question is to notice that the sequence given by $a_n = (2 + \sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n$ satisfies the recursive relations $a_{n+2} = 4a_{n+1} - a_n$. Therefore as $4$ is even we have that $a_{n+2}$ and $a_n$ have the same parity. So as $a_2 = 14$ is even, so are all even indexed terms of the sequence. Similarly $a_1 = 4$ is even and so does all odd indexed terms.

And now as $\lfloor (2 + \sqrt{3})^n \rfloor = a_n - 1$, as User1006 explained, we have the wanted result.

Comment: (+1) pretty close to what I was writing, but I believe the recursion is $a_{n+1}=4a_{n+1}\color{#C00000}{-}a_n$. Furthermore, since $a_0=2$ and $a_1=4$, we have that all the terms of the sequence must be even, as long as the recursion has integer coefficients.

Comment: @robjohn  $a_{n+2} = 4a_{n+1} - a_n$ in fact. Anyway thanks for noting. At first I wrote it as $a_{n+2} - 4a_{n+1} + a_n = 0$ and when I moved the last two terms to the other side I changed just one of the signs.

Comment: @robjohn (+1) for noting that every term is odd. I didn't look into that, as that wasn't the OP's question.

Comment: I posted and deleted [what I was writing](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033560) so you can see what I was talking about. I don't think it is too different from what you wrote. If you think it is, I will undelete it.

Comment: @robjohn I agree the answers are more or less the same, but I wouldn't mind undeleting your answer at all. After all I can't tell people what to do and even more I don't feel like I should give permissions to people what to post. Nevertheless I don't have anything against two similar answers. In my opinion it somehow enriches the answers and at the end the OP might find something different in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence
$$
a_n=\left(2+\sqrt3\right)^n+\left(2-\sqrt3\right)^n
$$
satisfies the recursion $a_n=4a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$. Furthermore, since $a_0=2$ and $a_1=4$, all the terms of the sequence are even. Thus, for $n\ge0$,
$$
\left(2+\sqrt3\right)^n=a_n-\overbrace{\left(2-\sqrt3\right)^n}^{\in(0,1]}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left\lfloor\left(2+\sqrt3\right)^n\right\rfloor=\overbrace{\ \ a_n-1\ \ }^\text{odd}
$$

Comment: This is essentially the same as Stefan4024's answer, but maybe it is different enough to provide another perspective.